# Finding threading bugs

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there any point trying to find threading problems at compile time?

I'm talking about data races, deadlocks, corrupted state etc...

Comment: If you would have a tool pointing you to threading problems at compile time, I'd say, *"Offcourse"*?!

Answer (score 4):

While this isn't compile time, you might want to check out [Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html):

> **Overview**
>
> Helgrind is a Valgrind tool for
>   detecting synchronisation errors in C,
>   C++ and Fortran programs that use the
>   POSIX pthreads threading primitives.
>
> The main abstractions in POSIX
>   pthreads are: a set of threads sharing
>   a common address space, thread
>   creation, thread joining, thread exit,
>   mutexes (locks), condition variables
>   (inter-thread event notifications),
>   reader-writer locks, spinlocks,
>   semaphores and barriers.
>
> Helgrind can detect three classes of
>   errors, which are discussed in detail
>   in the next three sections:
>
> 1. Misuses of the POSIX pthreads API.
> 2. Potential deadlocks arising from lock ordering problems.
> 3. Data races -- accessing memory without adequate locking or
>      synchronisation.
>
> Problems like these often result in
>   unreproducible, timing-dependent
>   crashes, deadlocks and other
>   misbehaviour, and can be difficult to
>   find by other means.
>
> Helgrind is aware of all the pthread
>   abstractions and tracks their effects
>   as accurately as it can. On x86 and
>   amd64 platforms, it understands and
>   partially handles implicit locking
>   arising from the use of the LOCK
>   instruction prefix.
>
> Helgrind works best when your
>   application uses only the POSIX
>   pthreads API. However, if you want to
>   use custom threading primitives, you
>   can describe their behaviour to
>   Helgrind using the ANNOTATE_* macros
>   defined in helgrind.h. This
>   functionality was added in release
>   3.5.0 of Valgrind, and is considered experimental.

Since Boost.Threads is based on POSIX pthreads ( at least on Linux ) I would guess that it would work for it as well.

Answer (score 2):

While I do not know of any compiler with explicit thread-safety diagnosis options, Coverity is static analysis tool which does provide checkers for concurrency issues, which by not being done at runtime could be *loosely* comparable to "compile time", since the compiler is a tool that before generating code does some static analysis for validity of the come, and that seems to be what your are looking for, not necessarily tied to *compile time*, ie before generating code...

If the static analysis tool understands the concurrency primitives then yes it is possible to do static analysis for threading problems. Whether a tool/compiler is at the point where those issues are correctly pointed out I have still to experience.

NB: At work we have used Coverity to do static analysis, but while we wade through all the "issues" pointed by the tool we have not yet enabled the concurrency checker so I cannot give any testimonial of how well it works. As for the other more common checkers, they pointed out a bunch of valid issues, as well as some innocuous issues, and a few false positives. I hope to check the output of the concurrency checker soon to judge myself its usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/debugging-threaded-applications/, for example. There is software dedicated to this task, like http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-thread-checker/.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see that you asked for a compile-time solution. Maybe this answer is still of relevance.